# Encoding and Decoding

Tags: binary, error-correcting-codes, computer-algebra, hamming-code, hamming-distance

I am trying to find an encoding function e:{0,1}^20→{0,1}^10 and a decoding function d:{0,1}^10→{0,1}^20. Goal is to find d and e so that maxBdH(d(e(B)),B) is as small as possible. Here, dH denotes the Hamming distance, and the maximum is taken over all possible bit arrays of length 20.

Haven't been able to find a suitable way to do this, need someone to point me in the right direction

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: @D.W., they first encode the string and then decode the string, so the distance is between an original 20-bit string and a 20-bit result of its encoding-decoding.

Comment: What is the context where you encountered this? Can you credit the original source? What is the motivation?

Comment: What are the best upper and lower bounds you have so far?  What's the best solution you have so far?  Please spend time trying to solve it yourself and [edit] the question to show what you've come up with so far and what progress you've amde.  It's easy to come up with an encoding where the Hamming distance is always $\le 10$, and it's easy to prove that Hamming distance $\ge 3$ is necessary.  Can you prove those statements?  Can you achieve even better?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156076/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74650234/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).